# Implementing an email invitation system in Ruby on Rails

Tags: authentication, email, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to implement an invitation system where authorized user can send an invitation with email to a friend. And if the invited person creates an account, the invitation sender collects points.

I am not using an auth gem such as devise or so, so I do not know how to write such a system.

Comment: [RailsTutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/) explains the process of creating a simple authentication system. I suggest you start there.

Comment: @D-side exactly!. I have followed the instructions and created an auth system, however i do not know how i can write an invitation system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this tutorial for an invitation system that I am currently working through which could be what you are looking for. You will need to create an Invite model and controller. Each time you need to invite a user, a new invite is created. With it, you can pass along an invitation token which can link back to the sender, ensuring the sender collects points upon successful signup. The email invitation relies on Rails ActionMailer to send, so with it you will need to incorporate a service such as sendgrid or mandrill. Good luck!

https://coderwall.com/p/rqjjca/creating-a-scoped-invitation-system-for-rails

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: You should also do it for this post. You can [edit] it to include the relevant information. It looks like it helped the OP so it would be ashame to have this answer deleted.

Comment: It would be difficult to quote the relevant information from the link in my post, as the scoped-invitation tutorial is wholly relevant to the OP's question. Should I add more information as to what the tutorial covers?

Comment: From [answer], an answer at Stack Overflow is supposed to be self-contained, that is, it should hold all of the information required to solve the question at hand, and provide links for further information. So take what is really required from the linked tutorial and quote it here.

Comment: It would be redundant to quote the relevant information in the link, as the tutorial is wholly relevant to the OP's question. Ideally, I would have left the link as a comment, but I need 50 points to do so : /. I will add a summary of the tutorial if that helps.